# python SQL statement with variables without using %s

Tags: python, sql, string, variables, impala

I hope i can be clear about my problem. thank you :)

I'm using impala connection (library: from impala.dbapi import connect).

In order to run a query i'm using the execute command:
`cursor.execute(query.value,  (year_var, month_var,day_var))`

Generally - it works just fine, also with variables. the problem begins when i use a SQL LIKE statement (e.g. like '%seo' - which contain %s in it).

The 1st argument (query.value) is a string:

```
create table bi_db.search_terms as
select search_query,search_contain,count(*) searches
from (
select  search_query,
case when lower(search_query) like '%logo%' then 'logo'
     when lower(search_query) like '%google%' then 'google'
     when lower(search_query) like '%facebook%' then 'facebook'
     when lower(search_query) like '%instagram%' then 'instagram'
     when lower(search_query) like '%etsy%' then 'etsy'
     when lower(search_query) like '%seo%' then 'seo'
     when lower(search_query) like '%social media%' then 'social media'
     else 'else' end as search_contain
from traffic_db.traffic_parq   a
where year = %s AND month = %s AND day = %s AND  controller = 'search'  and action in ('gigs','users')        
and search_query is not null and search_query<>'' ) t
group by search_query,search_contain
```

the second argument of the cursor.execute (e.g. (year_var, month_var,day_var)) refer to %s i'm putting on the query i run in order to use dynamic variables.

** The problem is that the python thinks it has 5 arguments instead of only 3. that caused because i have `%seo` and `%social` in the LIKE statments **

Anyone encountered this kind of problem? know how to solve it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `%%` for literal `%`.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape literal percent signs in the query (e.g. `%%seo%%`), although it would be cleaner to pass the patterns as parameters to `execute()` as well:

```
sql = """
create table bi_db.search_terms as
select search_query,search_contain,count(*) searches
from (
select  search_query,
case when lower(search_query) like %s then 'logo'
...
"""
cursor.execute(sql, ('%logo%', ...))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :)
Its problematic for me to change the execute paramerts becuase this is a generic script that should run on a lot of tables.

I have to fix the query in another way that won't contain %s in it at all.
You said that I could escape literal percent signs. How do i do it? I tried double %% sign and the python still returns an error .

Comment: Were you able to find solution ? I have similar problem, my SQL query contains date format `%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s` where `%d` and `%s` are the problem.